# How change a mention about user folder after user name changing correctly

Tags: 12.04, rvm

colleagues.

I renamed my username from **test** to **drobazko**.
Also I renamed a user folder from **/home/test** to **/home/drobazko**.
I am developing under Ruby rvm.
And I found out that the **/home/test/** path was mentioned in many files.
How Can I replace this line in files correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "sed" command to replace all occurrences of "foo" in a file with "bar" using the following syntax:

```
sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' filename
```

In your case it would be

```
sed -i 's/\/home\/test/\/home\/drobazko/g' filename
```

"filename" here can be a wildcard * or matching certain types of files (eg *.rb)